# Invalid Syntax Error: totals.setdefault(item,0) totals[item]+=rating[other][item]*sim

Tags: python-3.x, printing, syntax, syntax-error

Code:

```
def get_recommendations(rating, user, similarity=pearson):
    totals={}
    simSums={}
    for other in rating:
        #don't compare me to myself
        if other==user: continue
        sim=similarity(rating,user,other)

        #Ignore scores of zero or lower
        if sim<=0: continue
        for item in rating[other]:

            #Only score movies I haven't seen yet
            if item not in rating[user] or rating[user][item]==0:
                #Similarity * score
                totals.setdefault(item,0) totals[item]+=rating[other][item]*sim
                #Sum of Similarities
                simSums.setdefault(item,0)
                simSums[item]+=sim

        #Create the normalised list
        rankings=[(total/simSums[item],item) for item, total in totals.items()]

        #Return the sorted list
        rankings.sort()
        rankings.reverse()
        return rankings
```

I am trying to retrieve unseen movies for a user, and then create a rating for these movies then ranking them. However, my outcome brings the following error.

When I remove "totals[item]+=rating[other][item]*sim" the code works, however the ratings print as 0, rather than an accumulated rating.

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Please add a tag indicating what language you are programming in.

Comment: Just added for you, we are using Python 3.

Comment: `setdefault` doesn't really make sense for immutable values.  `totals[item] = totals.get(item, 0) + rating[other][item]*sim` is more readable.  Or use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)